# Subversion system with multiple remote project

Tags: git, svn, remote-server

This is my situation:
I have multiple online projects and some of them share some sub-projects.
Example: project A, B, C, D each of them on a server, with A and B that include D as a feature in a subfolder.

I would like to use a subversioning system like TortoiseSVN, for example, with all the projects in a central server, with me and colleagues that checkout and commit to this central server which automatically (in some way) update the committed files to the needed server.

Is there a way (possibly simple) to update files automatically to remote servers from a central subversion server?

Any help is appreciated...

Comment: That isn't a problem that subversion promises to solve - you want dependency management and package repositories.   If you're working in Java, consider using Maven.

Answer (score 0):

You mix at least two tasks (questions) in your single question

- How to manage shared code with Subversion
- How to deploy files from SVN-repo to real systems

(and second question isn't pure Subversion, it's more for "deploy tools" tag), but

- You can read, understand and use SVN externals for linking physically independent, but logically related repositories
- Post-commit hooks may work as first attempt for building deploy-tools of any complexity